# Incompatible pointer types sending 'class' to parameter of type CCMenuItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am making a 14 year old kid making a game in cocos2d. I am pretty new to cocos2d. I want to display the same coin sprite next to each other to make a pattern.

So I added this in my main gameplay layer:

```
- (void)coinPatterns {    
    menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:[Coins class], [Coins class], self, nil];
    [menu alignItemsHorizontally];
    [self addChild:menu];
}
```

And this is how I am initializing menu:

```
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setSpawnRate:50 forMonsterType:menu];
```

This is what is in my coins class:

```
- (id)initWithMonsterPicture
{
    self = [super initWithFile:@"coin.png"];
    if (self)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] screenRect];
        CGSize spriteSize = [self contentSize];
        posX =  screenRect.size.width + spriteSize.width * 0.5f;
        posY = 150;
        self.initialHitPoints = 1;
        self.animationFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self scheduleUpdate];
        inAppCurrencyDisplayNode.score = [Store availableAmountInAppCurrency];
    }
    coinValue = 3;
    return self;
}
- (void)spawn
{
    self.position = CGPointMake(posX, posY);
    self.visible = YES;
}
- (void)gotCollected {
    self.visible = FALSE;
    self.position = ccp(-MAX_INT, 0);
    [Store addInAppCurrency:coinValue];
}
```

I keep getting a `Incompatible pointer types sending 'class' to parameter of type 'CCMenuItem'`. Can someone please tell me how I should change the code so that this works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menuWithItems:` takes an array of `CCMenuItem` objects, you are sending a class itself. I don't know what the class `Coin` does, but if the purpose is to show an image and then do something when it's tapped I suggest you to do this:

```
CCMenuItem *myCoin1 = [CCMenuItemImage 
  itemFromNormalImage:@"coin.png" selectedImage:@"coinSelected.png" 
  target:self selector:@selector(coin1WasTapped:)];
CCMenuItem *myCoin2 ...
menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: myCoin1, myCoin2, myCoin3, ..., nil];
```

You should create a method `coin1WasTapped:` that will be called when the coin was tapped, you can "collect" the coins here. Maybe remove them from the `menu` or an animation.

If you are going to create many coins I suggest you to use a `for` loop to create them all in an array. This way it will be easier to manipulate later.

This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/cocos2d-buttons-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle) is really good, it can help you to understand better what you need to do and how to do it.

Good luck!

Comment: I did what you told me but it's still giving me a warning `Incompatible pointer types sending 'Coins *__strong' to parameter of type 'CCMenuItem *'`

Comment: What kind of object is `coin`?
Do you want them to behave like buttons?

Comment: No, the coins can be collected but I just want to make a horizontal line with the coins so they are in a pattern. I just wanted to use CCMenu so I can align the coins horizontally. Is there a better way of doing that without using CCMenu?